# How do I use LINQ to get all the Items that have a particular SubItem?

Tags: vb.net, linq, listviewitem

My software is designed to encrypt and decrypt files. The user loads the files to be processed into a ListView control. In the control, each item is the file path with one subitem, the type of process (ENCRYPT or DECRYPT).

I need to get a list of all ITEMS (the file paths) that have the "ENCRYPT" subitem, preferably with LINQ. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
Dim enclist As New ArrayList()
For i As Int32 = 0 To (lvwLoad.Items.Count - 1)
    If lvwLoad.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = "ENCRYPT" Then
        enclist.Add(lvwLoad.Items.Item(i).Text)
        count += 1
    End If
Next
```

I tried this:

```
Dim list As IEnumerable(Of String) = From item In lvwLoad.Items 
                                     Where item.SubItems(1).Text = "ENCRYPT"
```

But this statement can't access the `SubItems()` array. I know there's probably something simple I'm missing, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT: 
I know I can do this:

```
Dim enclist As New List(Of String)
For Each item As ListViewItem In lvwLoad.Items
    If item.SubItems(1).Text = "ENCRYPT" Then
        enclist.Add(item.Text)
    End If
Next
```

But I really want to know how to do this with LINQ.

Comment: Don't use the `ArrayList` anymore. Use the strongly typed `List(Of T)` instead.

Comment: I don't want to use `ArrayList` or `List(Of T)` at all. I want to use LINQ for my software. But thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: You say "This doesn't work" but you don't say what's not working about it.

Comment: @rossisdead: The LINQ statement I tried won't access any subitems unless I specify the item like this: `Items.Item(1).SubItems`

Comment: LINQ is just a method to select items from a collection. It supports multiple types of collections, with `List(of T)` being a very common one. Is it that the first subitem has to be `"ENCRYPT"` or do you want any of them to be "ENCRYPT"?

Comment: @Origin There is only one subitem for each item. And I want to get a list of ALL items with the subitem of ENCRYPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below, you need to cast items to `ListViewItem` so that you can access `SubItems`

```
Dim list  = From item In lvwLoad.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem) () _ 
                                     Where item.SubItems(1).Text = "ENCRYPT" 
                                     Select item.Text
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll remember that. Just needed to add `Select item.Text` after your code and it works great. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return lvwLoad.Items.Where(item => item.SubItems(1).Text = "ENCRYPT").Select(s => s.Text);

Dim list As IEnumerable(Of String) = From item In lvwLoad.Items 
                                 Where item.SubItems(1).Text = "ENCRYPT"
                                     Select item.Text
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: can you post vb.net version of this?

Comment: i updated it , I hope this will help though i never worked in vb.net.