# VB.NET using Linq to get data from Listview

Tags: vb.net, linq, listview

I am currently studying Linq to filtering data from Listview

for example , I have Listview table

[image]

I would like to get data which Emp Name is Rob BOB and Department is Developer

In order to make sure Linq is working, I was trying to find Rob BOB in listview table

I was trying

```
        Dim Conflicts = From ListItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
                       Select "Rob BOB" = ListItem.Text
```

and

```
        Dim Conflicts As IEnumerable(Of ListView) = From item In ListView1.Items
        Where item.SubItems(1).Text = "Rob BOB"
                                    Select item.Text

 For Each ConflictedGroup In Conflicts
        MsgBox(ConflictedGroup.ToString)
    Next
```

to get a data

However, it doesn't return anything or giving exception error

i was checking

[How do I use LINQ to get all the Items that have a particular SubItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407902/how-do-i-use-linq-to-get-all-the-items-that-have-a-particular-subitem)

to follow how to use linq for Listview, but doesn't work ..

Does anybody know how to use Linq for Listview ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, `item.SubItems(1).Text = "Rob BOB"` is incorrect.  The `Item.Text` maps to `SubItems(0)`.  `SubItems(1)` would be the address.  So that bit is searching the Address "column" for the name and should return nothing.

[image]

This works:

```
Dim dupes = myLV.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).
        Where(Function(w) w.Text.ToLowerInvariant = "ziggy jones").
        Select(Function(s) s.Text).ToList

For Each s As String In dupes
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

Output:

> Ziggy Jones
>   Ziggy Jones

Your second block would work like so:

```
Dim Conflicts = From ListItem In myLV.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem)()
                Where ListItem.Text = "Ziggy Jones"
                Select ListItem.Text
```

It seems like it might be more useful to collect the indicies of the dupes.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried second option t getting data however, it seems "Conflicts" variable doesn't get any results from Linq statement. Is there anyway to check data in the column  just like sql ? (or item.SubItems(1) is only way to access data in listview? )

Comment: `Conflicts` ends up with 2 items for me.  Maybe [edit] your post with the revised attempt.  Also, as I said, a simple List of the names that are dupes doesnt seem very useful - you'd have to find them again to do anything about it.

Comment: Also, rather than a ListView, if the data was in a `List(Of MyEmpClass)` you could bind it to a DGV without making copies of the data.  Then you could query, sort, filter and prune the list **much** more easily.