# Filter List view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to create a listview for showing tblProduct from an Access database and I want to know how to create a search function and a filter by price [This is my form design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Viwyg.png)

```
    Connect()
    Try
        testconn()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProduct", conn)

        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim myRow As DataRow
        For Each myRow In dt.Rows
            ListView1.Items.Add(myRow.Item(1))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(2))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(3))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(4))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(5))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(6))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(7))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(8))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(9))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(10))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(11))

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: When you press the button, change your SQL query to support a WHERE clause if needed.

Comment: [LINQ](https://www.dotnetperls.com/linq-vbnet) can be used on your listview

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508447/5444143)